# Generación de PDF y correo en php

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, fpdf

recurro nuevamente a ustedes para una ayuda. Estoy enviando una petición AJAX a un archivo PHP que esta generando un PDF (guardandolo en el servidor) con la libreria FPDF y en la misma plantilla envío un correo (con la librería PHPMAILER) con dicho archivo PDF. Veo que se ejecuta, se guarda el archivo en el servidor y se esta enviando el correo, pero no me da repuesta el AJAX.

```
$pdf->Output(); // PDF se genera y se muestra
$pdf->Output('F','billing/orden_pedido/colombia/'.$numero.'.pdf');//Se guarda archivo PDF en servidor

$urls = 'billing/orden_pedido/colombia/'.$numero.'.pdf';// Se busca el archivo PDF en el servidor

if (file_exists($urls)){
    $mail = new PHPMailer();//Se crea instancia para enviar correo
        
    $mail->isSMTP();//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;//Se usa SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';//Se establece el hostname de el servidor de correo
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';//'smtp.gmail.com';//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
    $mail->Port = 587;//587;// Se establece el puero
    
    $mail->Timeout=10;//Establece el timeout del servidor STMP en segundos
    
    $mail->Username = 'correo';//Cuenta de donde se enviará el correo
    $mail->Password = 'clave';// Se configura la clave de la cuenta
    
    $mail->setFrom('correo', utf8_decode('Orden de Pedido'));// De donde se envía correo con título
    
    $mail->addAddress('correo', 'Receptor');//Correo principal
    
    //Query para buscar los datos de los archivos adjuntos
    $orden_pedido_adjuntos = $link->query('SELECT * FROM orden_pedido_adjuntos WHERE ORDEN_PEDIDO_ADJUNTOS_PEDIDO_ID='.$val);
    
    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($cliente.' '.$number);// Asunto correo
    //Configuración para el cupero del correo
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('recursos/GRUPOESS2_email.jpg','logo','logo.png');
    $mail->Body .= '<img width="160px" src="cid:logo"><br><br>'; 
    $mail->Body .= utf8_decode("<font face='Tahoma, Arial'>Cordial saludo,</font>");
    $validar_archivos = 0;
    $array_archivos = array();
    if ($orden_pedido_adjuntos->num_rows > 0){
        while ($rowOpa = $orden_pedido_adjuntos->fetch_assoc()){
            $validar = $rowOpa['ORDEN_PEDIDO_ADJUNTOS_VALIDAR'];
            $ruta = $rowOpa['ORDEN_PEDIDO_ADJUNTOS_RUTA'];
            $nombre_archivo = $rowOpa['ORDEN_PEDIDO_ADJUNTOS_NOMBRE'];
            if (strpos($validar, 'CONTADO') !== false && strpos($validar, 'Sí') !== false){
                $validar_archivos = 1;
                array_push($array_archivos, $nombre_archivo);
            }else if (strpos($validar, 'CONTADO') === false && strpos($validar, 'Sí') !== false){
                $validar_archivos = 2;
                array_push($array_archivos, $nombre_archivo);
            }else if (strpos($validar, 'CONTADO') !== false && strpos($validar, 'Sí') === false){
                $validar_archivos = 3;
                array_push($array_archivos, $nombre_archivo);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    if ( $validar_archivos==1 ){//Si es contado y nuevo cliente, se debe adjuntar comprobante de pago y RUT
        $mail->Body .= utf8_decode("<br><br><font face='Tahoma, Arial'><strong>Orden de Pedido No. $numero</strong>
                    <br><br><strong>Cliente: $cliente</strong><br><br>Cliente nuevo, se adjunta RUT o fotocopia de CC para creación en Helisa.
                    <br><br>Se adjunta soporte de pago para su respectiva validación.
                    <br><br>Se adjunta la Orden de Pedido.
                    <br><br><br>Atentamente,<br><br><br><br>
                    <strong>$user_final</strong></font>");
        foreach ($array_archivos as $vali) {//Se recorre array para obtener los nombres de los archivos
            $rutas = $ruta.$vali;
            $mail->AddAttachment($rutas, $vali);// Se adjunta archivo en el correo
        }
    }else if ( $validar_archivos==2 ){//El cliente es nuevo pero paga a credito
        $mail->Body .= utf8_decode("<br><br><font face='Tahoma, Arial'><strong>Orden de Pedido No. $numero</strong>
                    <br><br><strong>Cliente: $cliente</strong><br><br>Cliente nuevo, se adjunta RUT o fotocopia de CC para creación en Helisa.
                    <br><br>Se adjunta la Orden de Pedido.
                    <br><br><br>Atentamente,<br><br><br><br>
                    <strong>$user_final</strong></font>");
        foreach ($array_archivos as $vali) {//Se recorre array para obtener los nombres de los archivos
            $rutas = $ruta.$vali;
            $mail->AddAttachment($rutas, $vali);// Se adjunta archivo en el correo
        }
    }else if ( $validar_archivos==3 ){//El cliente no es nuevo pero el pago es de contado
        $mail->Body .= utf8_decode("<br><br><font face='Tahoma, Arial'><strong>Orden de Pedido No. $numero</strong>
                    <br><br>Se adjunta el soporte de pago para su validación.
                    <br><br>Se adjunta la Orden de Pedido.
                    <br><br><br>Atentamente,<br><br><br><br>
                    <strong>$user_final</strong></font>");
        foreach ($array_archivos as $vali) {//Se recorre array para obtener los nombres de los archivos
            $rutas = $ruta.$vali;
            $mail->AddAttachment($rutas, $vali);// Se adjunta archivo en el correo
        }
    }else{
        $mail->Body .= utf8_decode("<br><br><font face='Tahoma, Arial'><strong>Orden de Pedido No. $numero</strong>
                    <br><br>Se adjunta la Orden de Pedido.
                    <br><br><br>Atentamente,<br><br><br><br>
                    <strong>$user_final</strong></font>");
    }
    $mail->isHTML(true);//Se habilita contenido HTML
    if ($canal==377){//Canal
        $url = 'billing/orden_pedido/colombia/'.$numero.'.pdf';// Se busca el archivo de pdf en el servidor
        $mail->AddAttachment($url, $numero.".pdf");// Se adjunta archivo OP en PDF en el correo
    }else{
        $url = 'billing/orden_pedido/miami/'.$numero.'.pdf';// Se busca el archivo de pdf en el servidor
        $mail->AddAttachment($url, $numero.".pdf");// Se adjunta archivo OP en PDF en el correo
    }
    
    if(!$mail->send()){// Error al enviar el correo
        $data['validar'] = 1;
        $data['mensaje'] = 'Mensaje no fue enviado<br>';
        $data['mensaje'] .= 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        registrar("Orden de pedido","orden_pedido",7,"Error al enviar correo con Orden de pedido No. $numero",$link);
    }else{// Correo enviado sin problemas
        $data['validar'] = 2;
        $data['mensaje'] = 'Archico creado y enviado correctamente';
        registrar("Orden de pedido","orden_pedido",4,"Se envía correo con Orden de pedido No. $numero",$link);
    }
}else{
    $data['mensaje'] = 'No ingresó';
}

echo json_encode($data);//Se devuelven valores capturados al AJAX
```

**Código JQUERY**

```
dataString = 'canal='+canal+'&userid='+userid+'&user_final='+user_final+'&val='+id+'&bodega='+bodega+
                                '&number='+data.number;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "orden_pedido_pdf.php",
    dataType: "text json",
    data: dataString,
    success: function (datas){
        alert(datas)
    },
    error: function (r1) {
        alert(r1.status)
    }
});
```

Pero como les digo no me muestra repuesta el success. Pero si veo que se ejecuta la plantilla. Averiguando encontré en la sesión con la opción de **status** podía saber que error me manda y veo que me manda el número 200. Estuve indagando sobre ese error y me dice que es por el JSON. Seguí buscando y encontré que debía cambiar el dataType: "text json" por:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
contentType: false, //importante enviar este parámetro en false
processData: false, //importante enviar este parámetro en false
```

Cuando lo hice ya me ingresa al success pero no he podido retomar los datos que me manda el archivo de PHP. Si alguien sabe el motivo y como puedo solucionarlo, les agradecería mucho.

Comment: Por favor, si alguien sabe la repuesta.. su ayuda urgente. Estoy que me vuelvo loco.. Muchas gracuas

Comment: He quitado la línea dataType: "text json", y funciona pero necesito retomar valores dependiendo de la ejecución del PHP y no he podido lograrlo           type: "POST",
url: "orden_pedido_correos.php",
data: dataStringe,                                                                                                            Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Compañeros. después de averiguar y averiguar, pude solucionar la falla. En mi archivo donde genero el correo Tenía el parámetro $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
La quite y ya me funciona correctamente. Aunque sinceramente ignoro el motivo, por lo que investigaré más a detalle, aunque si alguien sabe la razón les agradecería.

La ayuda la encontré en:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746932/parsererror-syntaxerror-unexpected-number-in-json